# How to count the number of letter in a string and remove duplicate letter in output

Tags: java

Hey i am  beginner in java programming and i have written a program to count the number of occurrence in string and i want to improve this code.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Letters
{
    public static void main(String let[]) throws IOException
    {
       InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(r);
        System.out.println("Enter The Sentense");
        String s = b.readLine();
        String store="";
        String store1="";

        for(int i=0;i<=s.length()-1;i++)
        {
            int count =0;
            store=s.charAt(i)+"";

            for(int j=0;j<=s.length()-1;j++)
            {
                store1=s.charAt(j)+"";
                if(store.equals(store1))
                {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(store+" : "+count);
        }
    }
}
```

And output i am getting for this is

```
Enter The Sentense
ddooooonnneeeeee
d : 2
d : 2
o : 5
o : 5
o : 5
o : 5
o : 5
n : 3
n : 3
n : 3
e : 6
e : 6
e : 6
e : 6
e : 6
e : 6
```

But i want to get my  output like this

```
Enter The Sentense
ddooooonnneeeeee
d:2
o:5
n:3
e:6
```

Any suggestion how can i do it.

Comment: if you want to improve your code go there(http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Rather than double looping over each character in the string, I would use a map to keep a tally of frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will help you in achieving this using HashMap Collection which will not allow duplicate keys.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Letters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter The Sentense");
        String s = in.nextLine();
        HashMap<Character,Integer> w = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
            w.put(s.charAt(i), w.get(s.charAt(i))==null?1:(w.get(s.charAt(i))+1));
        }
        for(char i:w.keySet()){
            System.out.println(i+":"+w.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a character array instead which keeps a track of each alphabet. 
Something like

```
int countLetter[] = new int[26];
```

then

```
 for(int i=0;i<=s.length()-1;i++)
        {
        countLetter[s.charAt(i) - 97] ++;
  }
```

Then print the contents

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `HashMap` whose key is the character you want to count and each time you encounter that character you simply update (`+1`) the value of the `HashMap` with the count/occurrences.

Here is an example:

```
//the frequency hashMap
HashMap<String, Integer> characterFrequencyMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
//here you reach characters of your string

    for(int x=0; x< s.length; x++){
        if(!s[x].equalsIgnoreCase(" ") )
        updateFrequencies(s[x].toLowerCase());
    }
```

Finally, this is the function that updates the character frequency

```
private void updateFrequencies(String keyCharacter){
    if(characterFrequencyMap.containsKey(keyCharacter)){
        int currentFrequency = characterFrequencyMap.get(keyCharacter);     
            characterFrequencyMap.replace(keyCharacter, currentFrequency+1);            
        }
        else{
            characterFrequencyMap.put(keyCharacter, 1);
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps. Please give it a try and let me know.

Comment: is it possible  to do it without Hashmap and scanner?if yes how

Comment: Why don't you use `Hashmap`  and `Scanner`? I thought you simply wanted to achieve the counting of character occurrences in the input string. - and I am suggesting doing it as I shown in my answer. Did you at least try this out?

Comment: yup i tried it out and its working but i dont have knowledge of hash and scanner i am currently on threads.

Comment: In that case, if the solution works then you need to accept the answer (so your question is marked as answered and does not appear under unanswered questions).

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.TreeSet;
public class Letters
{
    public static void main(String let[]) throws IOException
    {
       InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(r);
        System.out.println("Enter The Sentense");
        String s = b.readLine();
        String store="";
        String store1="";
        TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>();      
        for(int i=0;i<=s.length()-1;i++)
        {
            int count =0;
            store=s.charAt(i)+"";

            if(ts.contains(store) == false)
            { 
              for(int j=0;j<=s.length()-1;j++)
              {
                store1=s.charAt(j)+"";
                if(store.equals(store1))
                {
                    ++count;
                }
              }
             System.out.println(store+" : "+count);
             ts.add(store);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we can add unique elements to treeset. contains method of treeset checks whether particular element is already present or not. if it is already present then element is not added to treeset.

Comment: Descriptions belong into the answer itself, not into a comment. And please, be more specific. We don't know how experienced OP is, so the description should also work for a newb in programming.